# android + google map api v2 + current location

Tags: android, google-maps

i am creating an app with a google map view and i want this app to detect the current location of the user  and display the lat and long with a  marker on the map but all i can do until now is the display of the google map and the detection of current location without any marker displayed and without any text appear to display the lat and long

i did not add a marker until now because i do not know where to put it in the code and what is the best practice to do that

can anyone help me ???
this is the code of the:

## manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationgooglemapv2demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationgooglemapv2demo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API KEY" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## java file

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationgooglemapv2demo;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

First check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), it gives good indication on best strategies for getting user position.

Personally I usually start the map with a marker placed at the position retrivied with

```
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
```

and then I start listening for position update and move the marker.

It also depend on how accurate position you need for the pourpose of your application, if you don't need really accurate position but the area is sufficient maybe you can just use the`lastKnownLocation`.

You can try something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
          void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // redraw the marker when get location update.
          drawMarker(location);
        }

        if(location!=null){
           //PLACE THE INITIAL MARKER              
           drawMarker(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, locationListener);
    }
}

private void drawMarker(Location location){
    // Remove any existing markers on the map
    googleMap.clear();
    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(currentPosition)
    .snippet("Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "Lng:"+ location.getLongitude())
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
    .title("ME"));
}
```

Also you don't need the Activity class to `implements LocationListener`, you can just define a listener and register it as I did above

P.S. I don't have an editor son my code can contain typo

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: @ drChivas that is exactly what i want to do i need to display the current location of the user on the map with the text that contain lat and long but i did not know how to do that

Comment: what if the last known location comes as null

Comment: This was awesome and right on the money. FYI this was a syntax error:
.snippet("Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "Lng:"+ location.getLongitude()));

I had to remove the final parenthesis and semi-colon because it was invalidating the following .icon() etc sections.

Comment: @DrChivas can u tell me how can i show current location if i press button of map on right hand side

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem, and found a way to do it using the Google Maps API:

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
        if(mMap != null){
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
        }
    }
};
```

and then set the listener for the map:

```
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

This will get called when the map first finds the location.

No need for `LocationService` or `LocationManager` at all.

Comment: This works as expected. Thanks. But I want to modify it to be able to return a double[] containing lat and lng. How is that possible? This looks strange to me. :/

Answer (score 1):

Full shortcut for defining the Google Map android v2 in android......

XML File :

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Menifest file :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Map permission Starts -->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemoapiv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemoapiv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<!-- Map permission Starts -->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapdemoapiv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapDetail" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your Key" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

Activity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
{
   GoogleMap googleMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    GetCurrentLocation();

    }

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (googleMap == null) {

        Log.e("", "Into null map");
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(
                MainActivity.this));

        if (googleMap != null) {
            Log.e("", "Into full map");
            googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}

private void GetCurrentLocation() {

    double[] d = getlocation();
    Share.lat = d[0];
    Share.lng = d[1];

     googleMap
            .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Share.lat, Share.lng))
                    .title("Current Location")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.dot_blue)));

             googleMap
                .animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(Share.lat, Share.lng), 5));
}

public double[] getlocation() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

    Location l = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
        l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
        if (l != null)
            break;
    }
    double[] gps = new double[2];

    if (l != null) {
        gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
        gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
    }
    return gps;
}
```

Comment: Can we get location through Google Maps API? because some devices doesnt have GPS.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use:

```
Location currentLocation =
     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Answer (score 0):

easy like that:

after this -

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="Your Key" />
```

put this -

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />
```